# Does anybody have working network-config for headless boot ? Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, headless

As stated in the Title. I have tried several combinations and can't get it to work. There are no samples I could find on internet... everybody is happy with dhcp default settings... ???

I have tried to put there:

```
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
    eth0:
        dhcp4: false
        dhcp4-overrides:
            use-dns: false
        gateway4: 192.168.0.1
        addresses:
            - 192.168.0.10/24
        match:
            driver: bcmgenet smsc95xx lan78xx
        optional: true
        set-name: eth0
```

Nothing,

Next:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp4-overrides:
                use-dns: no
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            addresses:
                - 192.168.0.10/24
            optional: true
            set-name: eth0
```

And few other variations, nothing works...

Comment: Please check here: `cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml` Is your ethernet interface actually eth0? `ip a`

Comment: agree with @chili555 eth0 has been changed to predictable network names so is not longer use.  Please look at `ip link show` and change accordingly if it is not eth0.

Comment: @chili555 / Rinzwind – thanks guys, that will be the issue most likely. I can't check it though at the moment :) its headless deployment. I kind of hoped the old config from 20.10 would work :)

Comment: I still can't confgure Ubuntu headless. With Raspbian is trivial. With Ubuntu I try writing network-config and it doesn't work. How did you solve it?

Comment: @05032MendicantBias Please start your own new question.